# Looping through a DateTime object array

Tags: php

I have been struggling with traversing php's objects. I have the following DateTime object in an array, but am having trouble iterating through it. What am I doing wrong?

```
// print_r($calendar_days);
Array
(
    [0] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2016-04-06 00:00:00
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Europe/Helsinki
        )

    [1] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2016-04-13 00:00:00
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Europe/Helsinki
        )

    [2] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2016-04-20 00:00:00
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Europe/Helsinki
        )

    [3] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2016-04-27 00:00:00
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Europe/Helsinki
        )

)
```

**PHP**

```
<?php foreach ($calendar_days as $key => $value){ ?>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="day-container">
      <strong> <?php echo $key->date; ?></strong>
    </div>
  </a>
<?php }
```

Thanks.

Comment: it should be `$value->date;`.

Comment: I tried that, but got Message: Undefined property: DateTime::$date

Comment: `<?php echo $value->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example ideone [here](https://ideone.com/djWPMn).

Essentially your current code is trying to access the member variable `date` on the `$key` of the array, so it is trying to do something like;

`echo 0->date;`

PHP doesn't understand exactly what you mean, so you won't be getting the output you expect. What you want to do is access the value (the actual `DateTime` object) and use that to output the dates instead, like so;

`echo $value->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

You need to remember you're handling `DateTime` objects, so just trying to access `->date` won't work as you expect. To my knowledge the `DateTime` object does not allow you to directly access its properties and instead if you want to print out the date you have to use it's public functions instead `->format()`

You can find the full docs for `DateTime` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

**Edit**: As mentioned @barat, you will no longer need `$key => $value` now that you are not trying to access the `$key` so you can omit `$key`:

`foreach ($calendar_days as $value) { ... }`

Comment: BTW ... if You're iterating through Array and don't need keys just do it like:

foreach($calendar_days as $date) {echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');}

Comment: Aye you don't, but since he had it originally I thought I'd just leave it in to leave the code closer to the original, and just in case he had some other reason for using the `$key`

Comment: My comment was more to user3442612 - I'm sure that for You it's common knowlage :)

Comment: Ohhhhh, the value is an object. I feel kind of dumb now. Thanks for the clear explanation.